# Disconnected from metro (1001: "Stream End Encountered")

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-go

I am getting an error message :

Disconnected from metro (1001: "Stream End Encountered").

This often happens when I leave the app idle (on screen ) for a few minutes.